# Getting bibliography in the main file

Tags: bibliographies, bibtex, elsarticle

I am submitting a journal paper and, if I'm not mistaken, I suspect they expect all parts of the manuscript in the same file, including references. A minimal example is:

```
\documentclass[preprint,12pt]{elsarticle}

\begin{document}

\cite{turing_checking_1949}

\bibliographystyle{plain}
\bibliography{references}

\end{document}
```

The question is: How can I omit the line `\bibliography{references}`, paste the contents of `references.bib` into the main file, and still get the same bibliography result?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are close: What you need to do is copy and paste the contents not of the file `references.bib`, but of the file `\jobname.bbl`. The latter is a file that's created by BibTeX and is read in by LaTeX when it creates the pdf file, `\jobname.pdf`.

Let's assume you've created the formatted bibliography successfully (by running BibTeX) and that all citation call-outs are resolved correctly. I suggest you open the file `\jobname.bbl` -- any ordinary text editor will do -- and copy and paste its contents to overwrite the instruction

```
\bibliography{references}
```

in the file `\jobname.tex`. Then, re-run LaTeX one or more time to verify that the copy and paste operation was successful.